# LockInfo HOW TO

Tags: iphone

I found this about LockInfo SDK:
http://lockinfosdk.wikispaces.com/

BUT I have a question:
Let's suppose i get an idea an succeed to code it right, HOW would I install/deploy it on my iPhone, or share it via Cydia!??!?!??!
Thanks in advance,
crifei93mod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually install it by creating a DEB file (lots of tutorials online), SCP it to your phone and run "dpkg -i".  For Cydia, you need to either create a Cydia source (saurik has details on www.saurik.com) or host it with a reputable source like ModMyI.